# Type problems in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am writing a function to find the integer divisors of a real number. When I run the code, I get the following errors:

```
Clean solutions.hs:70:33:
    Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of `truncate'
    from the context (RealFrac a)
      bound by the type signature for divisors :: RealFrac a => a -> [a]
      at Clean solutions.hs:70:1-74
    Possible fix:
      add (Integral a) to the context of
        the type signature for divisors :: RealFrac a => a -> [a]
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `(truncate (n / x))'
    In the expression: (truncate (n / x)) == (n / x)
    In the first argument of `filter', namely
      `(\ x -> (truncate (n / x)) == (n / x))'

Clean solutions.hs:70:59:
    Could not deduce (Enum a)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence `2.0, 3.0 .. n / 2'
    from the context (RealFrac a)
      bound by the type signature for divisors :: RealFrac a => a -> [a]
      at Clean solutions.hs:70:1-74
    Possible fix:
      add (Enum a) to the context of
        the type signature for divisors :: RealFrac a => a -> [a]
    In the second argument of `filter', namely `[2.0, 3.0 .. n / 2]'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely
      `filter (\ x -> (truncate (n / x)) == (n / x)) [2.0, 3.0 .. n / 2]'
    In the expression:
      1
      : filter (\ x -> (truncate (n / x)) == (n / x)) [2.0, 3.0 .. n / 2]
```

I am finding it hard to understand what I'm doing wrong, despite spending an hour or two brushing up on types in Haskell. My code is below:

```
divisors :: RealFrac a => a -> [a]
divisors n = 1 : filter (\x -> (truncate (n/x)) == (n/x)) [2.0, 3.0.. n/2]
```

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Finding divisors is really not something you should use `RealFrac` for. It's more of an integral thing, so `divisors :: Integral a => a -> [a]` would be more appropriate. I suspect you went to `RealFrac` because of dividing with `/`. If that's right, use `quot` (or possibly `div`) to divide integral types, and `rem` (or `mod`, if you want positive remainders for negative numbers) for the remainder, ``divisors n = 1 : filter ((== 0) . (n `rem`)) [2 .. n `quot` 2]`` would be the corresponding (inefficient) implementation for your attempt.

Comment: Please define "integer divisors of a real number". What are the integer divisors of 7.6, or of pi, supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
 divisors :: (RealFrac a, Enum a) => a -> [a]
 divisors n = filter (\x -> n/x == fromIntegral (truncate (n/x))) [1.0..(n/2)]
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find the integer divisors of a Real number - the input to the function is not Integral.

Comment: @Sam That doesn't really make sense. The divisor you try is always an integral value, you check whether the quotient is an integral value, so if it ever succeeds, the input is the product of two integral values, hence an integral value.